# Can I call a Win32 API from the Visual Studio Immediate Window?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, debugging, winapi

I'm debugging a C++ Win32 application and I'd like to call an arbitrary Win32 API from the context of that process, as though the program had run this line of code:

```
DestroyWindow(0x00021c0e);
```

But entering that into the Immediate Window gives:

```
CXX0017: Error: symbol "DestroyWindow" not found
```

**Edit:** Using the full name of the function, `{,,user32.dll}_NtUserDestroyWindow@4`, I can get the Immediate Window to understand which function I mean and display the function's address:

```
{,,user32.dll}_NtUserDestroyWindow@4
0x76600454 _NtUserDestroyWindow@4
```

but when I try to call it, this happens:

```
{,,user32.dll}_NtUserDestroyWindow@4(0x00021c0e);
CXX0004: Error: syntax error
```

Is it even possible to call a C function from the Immediate Window like this, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have the function address (as you've done in the updated question), you can try casting it to a function pointer and calling it:

```
(*(BOOL (*)(HWND))0x76600454)((HWND)0x00021c0e)
```

The first part of that casts the address to `BOOL (*)(HWND)`, which is a pointer to a function taking an `HWND` parameter and returning `BOOL`.  Then, the function pointer is dereferenced and called.  Make sure to get the parameters correct, otherwise bad things will happen.  On 64-bit systems, and `HWND` might be 64 bits, so you might not be able to get away with passing the parameter as an `int`.

**Edit:** See the comments for the full story.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but... That gives me `CXX0004: Error: syntax error`.  Replacing the Windows types (`BOOL` and `HWND`) with primitive types (`int` in both cases) improves things, but I then get `CXX0014: Error: missing operand`. (I'm in a 32-bit process, BTW.)

Comment: The VS debugger's really bad at parsing function pointer types, apparently.  Try creating a typedef for it.  Put `typedef BOOL (*DESTROYWINDOW)(HWND);` in your code, then write `(*(DESTROYWINDOW)0x76600454)((void*)0x00021c0e)` in the debugger.

Comment: @Adam: Yay! (but a qualified one). By adding your `typedef` to my code, *and* actually using the `typedef` in the code so that the compiler doesn't throw the definition away, *and* breaking the execution of the process within the compilation unit where I used the `typedef`, I can now call DestroyWindow from the immediate window.  Thanks!  It's a shame to have to jump through these hoops to do it, but at least it's possible.

Comment: This is absolutely terrible.  I just had the same experience.  This is a huge Visual Studio fail.

Comment: Anyone know how to do it using .call in NTSD?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that the C++ EE is having problems resolving the context of DestroyWindow.  Try the following

```
{,,user32}DestroyWindow(0x00021c0e);
```

I'm not sure if the method invocation syntax supports this style of qualification (only used it for casting in the past).  But it's worth a shot.

**EDIT** You may or may not need to add a ! after the closing }.  It's been awhile since I've used this syntax and I often confuse it with the equivalent windbg one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already tried that and it doesn't work.  And I've tried decorating it as `_DestroyWindow@4` etc. as well, all the way up to the fully qualified `{,,user32.dll}_DestroyWindow@4`, with no joy.

Comment: @JaredPar: +1 for helping to improve the situation - see my edited question.  I can now get it to understand which function I mean, but I still can't make it call it.

Comment: @Richie, thanks!  +1'd your answer as well.  Wow, by the way.

Comment: @JaredPar: Thanks... I'm slightly embarrassed that I didn't figure out how to get the right function name sooner, given that I wrote a blog article on exactly that problem earlier this year: http://entrian.com/blog/setting-a-visual-studio-breakpoint-on-a-win32-api-function-in-user32dll/ 8-)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround, but I'd still prefer to get the Immediate Window to work.

The workaround is:

- get the address of the function, as shown in the question
- use the Disassembly window to go to that address, and put a breakpoint there
- do something to the application to make it call `DestroyWindow`
- step back up the call stack to the caller of `DestroyWindow`, which looks like this:

  6D096A9D  push        ecx
  6D096A9E  call        dword ptr ds:[6D0BB4B8h]
- put a breakpoint on the `push ecx` instruction, and clear the one on `DestroyWindow`
- hit Continue, and again do something to the application to make it call that code
- note down the value of `ecx`
- change the value of `ecx` in the debugger to the desired value and step over the `push/call`
- restore the value of `ecx` and use Set Next Statement to go back to the `push`, then Continue

It's longwinded, but it works.  It assumes you can make the application call the appropriate API at will.